# Why this sed command prints all the lines?

Tags: ubuntu, sed, command-line

Why this sed command:
`sed /^a/,/i$/p`
prints all lines and not just the lines that beginning with "a" and end with "i"?
It is not too clear to me how `sed /BEGIN/,/END/p` works.

STDIN:

```
arthuri
John
Johnny
Michael
```

STDOUT:

```
arthuri
arthuri
John
John
Johnny
Johnny
Michael
Michael
```

Comment: You're missing the `-n` option of `sed`, or you need to replace `p` with `!d`.

Comment: Also `sed` only starts looking for the end address on next line after the one matching the start address, it won't start and end on the same line (contrary to `awk`'s `start,end`)

Comment: If you want lines "beginning with a and ending with i", use `sed -n '/^a.*i$/p'`

Comment: @glennjackman, or `grep -x 'a.*i'`, or `sed '/^a/!d; /i$/!d'` (with possible variation in behavior for lines containing bytes that can't be decoded into characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` by defaults prints the pattern space at the end of each cycle as long as the `d` command has not been invoked.

That can be disabled with the `-n` option, or by making the first line of the `sed` script: `#n`.

So, here, in addition to that default printing, you're telling `sed` to *also* print the pattern space starting with the lines that starts with `a` and ending with the first line *after that* that ends with `i`.

The first line of your input (`arthuri`) starts with `a`, but there's no line after than that ends with `i`, so the `/^a/,/i$/` range is never terminated and all lines are printed (twice because of the default printing at the end).

`sed` ranges will always include at least 2 lines (except in the special case where the start is on the last line of the input).

To allow the start and end lines to be the same (like `arthuri` which happens to both start with `a` and end in `i`), you can use `awk` instead:

```
awk '/^a/, /i$/'
```

Or `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^a/ .. /i$/'
```

If you wanted to print the lines that start with `a` and end in `i`, you wouldn't use an address range, but just:

```
sed '/^a/!d; /i$/!d'
```

Or:

```
sed '/^a.*i$/!d'
```

Or:

```
sed -n '/^a.*i$/p'
```

Though here, you might as well use `grep`:

```
grep -x 'a.*i'
```

Note that `^`, `*` and `$` are special characters in the syntax of many shells. Generally, you want to quote `sed` code arguments.